# Smooth scrolling on same page when clicking the navigation bar (About, Portfolio...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to make a smooth scrolling to different parts of my page when clicking on navigation bar. 
I have googled this but I found codes that I don't understand, they don't explain where I should put my info, they just throw a long code with no indication of how to adapt it to my case. I would really appreciate some help.
here is my codepen.

```
`https://codepen.io/aabla/full/aYYOxy`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an exemple on this page :

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

And everything is explained in comments.. There is simpler ways, but this one is really complete..

If you want to make this work, you have to call jQuery first.

**EDIT**

Here is your codepen working :

> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEBOEg

Plus, in yours you had some mistakes on ID attributes (The IDs of the links were not equal to those of the `<div>` elements), this could not work anyway..